# TSQL get period number of a date (4weeks period)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

a year can be divided into periods of 4 weeks. 
For this year 30dec will be in period 13 and 31 dec in period 1 of 2019.
Is there a SQL function i can use? DATEPART or something?

if not, what can I use?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: This is also a perfect use-case for a Calendar Table.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your definition of "week" is the same as SQL Server's you can use:

```
select (datepart(week, date_col) + 3 / 4) as four_week_period
```

If you want to start the week on the first day of the year, then:

```
select (datediff(day, datefromparts(year(date_col), 1, 1), date_col) + 27 / 28)
```

Comment: The `week` datepart is controlled by the value in `SET DATEPART`. So you can set your week delimiter to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may also filter from this:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) Period_Id,
date as FirstWeekDay,
dateAdd(day, 28, date) as LastWeekDay  --divide the days into periods of 4 weeks.  
FROM table 
WHERE DATENAME(dw, date) IN ('Monday')   
ORDER BY date
```